# RecyclerView error everytime Json result only has one item

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

My recycler view is always error whenever the the api server only returns one json data. I am doing a food recommender system using zomato and everytime the search query returns only one restaurant, it doesnt show it. Just when it's only one restaurant. It works just fine when it's more than one.

My code:

[First part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koqQb.png)

[Second part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfpHo.png)

Sorry I don't know how to write the code in the post yet, so I post it in form of a screen shot...

Oh, the json format of the zomato api (the /search) can be seen in this page https:// developers . zomato . com/ documentation?lang=id#!/restaurant/search

Comment: Paste the code in your post, highlight it, and click the {} button. That will format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
filterAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, filterRestaurantData.size() - 1)
```

which will pass (1, 0) when only one item is in the list.

But the method takes the parameters (start, count)

so you should get the size before you add like:

```
int oldSize = filterRestaurantData.size();
filterRestaurantData.addAll(searchResult...)
```

and later use:

```
int numAdded = filterRestaurantData.size() - oldSize;
filterAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize, numAdded);
```